# How do I navigate through each item of a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

So, I know you can navigate through a 2D array with something like

```
arr1.each do |a1|
  a1.each do |a2|
    puts a2
```

however what I am trying to do is a little different. I have 2 sets of values stored in arrays and I want to be able to cycle through them and populate a dropdown menu from the information.

So I have data like:

```
names = ["bob", "frank", "tim"] 
id = [1, 2, 3]
```

which gets returned in an array from a method like this:

```
def method_name
  #stuff
  return names, id
end
```

What I want to be able to do in the view is pair the corresponding indexes with each other. So, for the above example, `bob-1` `frank-2` `tim-3` I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried slicing and nested loops and have also tried with a hash being returned instead of an array. I'm lost.

If anyone has any information on how to pull the information the way I am trying to do it, or another simpler way to do it I would really appreciate the input.

Comment: You should check out Nathan's answer. It's more Rubyish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rare case in Ruby where iterating on the index is helpful:

```
(0...names.size).map do |idx|
  "#{names[idx]}-#{id[idx]}"
end
```

Comment: You sir/ma'am are a hero. I was not even aware of the map method before. I'm glad I asked because my headache is already smaller haha.

Thanks again @seph!

Answer (score 2):

`names.zip(id).map { |e| e.join('-') }`

`zip` combines the two arrays into an array of arrays like this:

`[['bob', 1], ['frank', 2], ['tim', 3]]`

`map` loops through each of 3 elements of the outer array and converts each inner array into a string by joining its two elements together with a dash using `join`.

See [zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), and [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) documentation.

Generally speaking, when researching array manipulation in Ruby, you'll want to look at the docs both for Array and the docs for Enumerable.